# Application bar-style of automatic icon coloring elsewhere in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

When I add an icon button to the application bar the system takes care of displaying the icon in white if the dark theme is in use and displaying the icon in black if the light theme is in use.  Can I use this automatic coloring elsewhere in my application?  I would like to take an icon image from the SDK directory and use it on a normal button, and it would be great if I could get the system to display either white or black depending on the theme.  For now I'm doing it manually using a converter but if there's a way to automatically do it that would be cleaner.  Does anyone know of a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Button Background="{StaticResource PhoneContrastBackgroundBrush}" >
   <Button.OpacityMask>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/icon.png"/>
   </Button.OpacityMask>
</Button>
```

icon.png must be white

**[EDIT]**

OR (Draw a circle around them) using SDK image (appbar.basecircle.rest.png)

```
<Style x:Key="FlatStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Canvas Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                                        <Rectangle Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">
                                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/appbar.basecircle.rest.png"/>
                                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                        </Rectangle>
                                        <Rectangle Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" OpacityMask="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Grid>

                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Usage:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource FlatStyle}" BorderThickness="0" Width="48" Height="48">
                <Button.BorderBrush>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/appbar.favs.rest.png"/>
                </Button.BorderBrush>
            </Button>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Any ideas how I might be able to layer 2 images on top of each other while still using this technique?  I'm using the check and cancel images that come with the SDK and I'd like to draw a circle around them (was using the circle image that comes with the SDK).

Comment: handle a `Visible` property of each images

Comment: You must declare button style and use them. Please see my post changes

Comment: Thanks ebattulga that is pretty amazing.

Comment: Not sure if it's an emulator issue but the Pressed animation isn't working quite right for me.  Looking at the code I think it's supposed to invert the image (it looks like it changes the foreground color to the background and visa versa).  But for me when I click the button I get a white square in the top left corner and the rest of the button stays the same.  I'm pretty sure I have everything copied correctly so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: You can also take a loo at the complete article here: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Creating-theme-friendly-UI--in-WP7-using-OpacityMask